# Web font not showing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-face

http://miche.com/

This is the strangest thing. We're using two web fonts and their varying weights on the above page: Benton Sans and Jubilat, both of which we have licenses for. The h2 ("Interested in joining Miche?" "Already a Miche Representative?") is set to be Jubilat Regular, and is properly showing up in Firefox; however, the h1 ("Welcome!") is Jubilat Light, and appearing as Times New Roman.

Both weights are generated with Font Squirrel.
Both are hosted on the same server.
Both are coded in the same way.
I've reuploaded the files.
I've tried if IE so FF doesn't try to use .eot.
Before you say it: Yes, I have tried Bulletproof.

Why is Regular showing up when Light isn't? I wonder if I'm just not using the right combination of CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'JubilatLight';
    src: url('https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.eot');
    src: url('https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.svg#JubilatLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
#main-container h1.jubilat {
    font-family: "JubilatLight";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #701271;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: HEADS UP: I figured it out, but Stack won't let me post my answer until 6 hours after asking the question since I don't have 100 rep, apparently... MAKES SENSE.

Comment: This helped, but leaves me with a question: I can't do this with absolute URLs? Le sigh

Comment: Try it with absolute links, test in Firefox. If it doesn't work, you'll know it needs to be relative. Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. Firefox wasn't accepting absolute links, and instead wanted relative. Coupled with Mo'Bulletproof, I was able to get it to show up like so:

```
@font-face{ /* for IE */
font-family:JubilatLight;
src:url(/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.eot);
}
@font-face { /* for non-IE */
font-family:JubilatLight;
src:url(http://:/) format("No-IE-404"),url(/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.ttf) format("truetype");
}
#main-container h1.jubilattest {
    font-family: "JubilatLight";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #701271;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and then my HTML:

```
<div id="main-container">
   <h1 class="jubilattest">WELCOME!</h1>
</div>
```

Now that I've figured that out, I'll be able to fix the other fonts. Thank you three for your suggestions.

Comment: may I suggest that you accept the correct answer (this one) and give the others an upvote for their efforts?

Comment: @Bazzz Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't have enough reputation to accept my own answer until tomorrow, or even upvote the others.

Comment: Firefox evidently by default doesn't support fonts that are hosted externally. So you can host them locally, use a relative path to the font, and/or configure your server to allow access to them (eg. answer by @Guido-Palacios)

Answer (score 7):

Just want to let you know, there's also a way by configuring the htaccess (discribed by [Yu-Jie Lin](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/05/font-face-and-cross-domain-cross-origin.html))

his code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Brilliant for an apache noob like me!

Answer (score 4):

Your fonts are not correctly uploaded/linked.

[jubilatlightwebfont.woff](https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.woff) for example gives a 404 error.

Take a look at the Web-Console of Firefox. It throws some errors, for example:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "JubilatLight" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: https://bc.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/jubilatlightwebfont.ttf @ https://www.miche.com/FileUploads/CMS/Documents/MicheCorp092911v2.css
```

(btw: the `h2` elements use `Times New Roman` too, for me.)

Comment: It gives a 404, but it's showing up in the server. So is the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's showing up in the server"? on the ftp?

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at your CSS and it looks like you aren't correctly defining your font for your H2, so it's defaulting to TimesNewRoman:

```
#main-container h2.jubilat {
 color: #701271;
 font-family: "jubilat"; // <----------------
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It's actually my h1 tag that's having the problem. h2 is showing fine.

Comment: HEADS UP: I figured it out, but Stack won't let me post my answer until 6 hours after asking the question since I don't have 100 rep, apparently... MAKES SENSE.

Answer (score 0):

try to use implemented base64-encoded font-files within the css-doc:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"font-name";
  src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,[paste-64-code-here]);
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:400;
}
```

source: http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri

it worked perfectly...